# mongodb dump with date condition

Tags: json, mongodb, bson

I am trying to take a dump of offline mongodb using the following condition. But getting the following error every time.

```
./mongodump -d mylocaldb -c abcollection -q '{createDate: {$gte: ISODate("2014-09-27T12:20:00Z")}}' --dbpath /data/mongodb/
```

> **assertion: 16619 code FailedToParse: FailedToParse: Bad characters in value: offset:19**

Tried various tips on stackoverflow but none of them seems to  be working for open ended date query ?

Any Clues ?

Answer (score 1):

- It seems that ISODate("2014-09-27T12:20:00Z") is not supported in **mongodump**, just replace it with `Date(<milliseconds>)` or `{$date: <milliseconds>}`;
- `<milliseconds> = ISODate("2014-09-27T12:20:00Z").getTime()` in mongo shell.

Comment: tried that. but looks like nothing is getting dumped even with no query clause. So it may not be a date issues but something else. Although it is creating folders but not putting any BSON files.

No Error Either. 

Any Clues. 

`./mongodump -d mylocaldb -c abcollection --dbpath /data/mongodb/`

Comment: As you didn't specify `-o path`, BSON files should be at `dump/mylocaldb/` of current directory. If there is none, check whether `mylocaldb` and `abcollection` exist. You can run an instance against `/data/mongodb/` and connect it with client (such as mongo shell) to check it. Generally, successive dump will display a summary showing dumped objects.

Comment: Surprisingly, Dump is working when online but when i use with DBPath for offline dump, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Use {$date: miliseconds} with miliseconds is the number for ISODate("2014-09-27T12:20:00Z") in this case is 1411820400000.

```
./mongodump -d mylocaldb -c abcollection -q '{createDate: {$gte: { $date: 1411820400000 }}}' --dbpath /data/mongodb/
```

But 2014-09-27 is pretty recent date. Make sure there are data inserted from that date onwards?